# hyperlink is dropped to new line

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, newline, ellipsis

This is my `aspx` code,

```aspx
<div class="ellipsis">
Body Text Body Text Body Text Body Text Body   
Text Body Text Body Text Body Text Body !!!
</div>
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server">
    <span style="color: Maroon; font-style: italic; font-size: small;">
        More..
    </span>
</asp:HyperLink>
```

CSS

```css
.ellipsis
{ 
    width:               250px;
    white-space:         nowrap;
    overflow:            hidden;
    text-overflow:       ellipsis;
    -o-text-overflow:    ellipsis;
    -ms-text-overflow:   ellipsis;
    -moz-binding:        url('ellipsis.xml#ellipsis');
}
```

I want to show single line likes

```
 Body Text Body Text ...More..
```

But the hyperlink `HyperLink1` is dropped to new line . How can I fix it ?

This is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JntkC/) !

Comment: Can you explain why you have `display:block` in the CSS? (Removing it won't help, but I'm curious why you put it in there; what you think display:block does exactly.)

Comment: Thanks Mr Lister , I've removed it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a style:

```
float:left;
```

to both the div and the link

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend using floats for this. While it does do the trick, it changes the layout of the page and is unneccessary for such a small change. It would be just as easy to fix by changing the display type of the div to inline-block.

```
.ellipsis
{
  display: inline-block;
  ...
}
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JntkC/2/

Answer (score 0):

Adding the style to the `div` works. See the updated version of your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JntkC/1/

Add this line to the CSS

```css
float: left;
```

Comment: Technically true, but you should put it in the CSS. That's where it belongs.